# Dynamic URL with tuckey urlrewritefilter

Tags: java, regex, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have multiple links like

```
- http://example.com/link1/title-with-detail
- http://example.com/link2/title-with-detail
- http://example.com/link3/title-with-detail
```

and so on...

I have a tuckey rule which is working perfectly fine:

```
    <rule>
        <from>^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/type/([a-z]+)$</from>
        <to>/page?slug=$2&amp;type=$3</to>
    </rule>
```

For link like 
    - http://example.com/link1/title-with-detail/type/text

But when I use this rule, i.e.

```
<rule>              
        <from>^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$</from>
        <to>/page?slug=$2</to>
</rule>
```

my page breaks, because in  the slug is getting parameters such as styles.css, functions.js, etc. For this I tried to use conditions of tuckey to exclude the text which is equal to the text mentioned before, i.e. `js`, `css`, `png` etc. But I don't know what exact condition to form, as I am newbie to regular expressions. Please guide.

Comment: I see, then you can try `^\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)(?!.*\.(?:js|css|png|jpg)$).*$` to exclude all URLs ending with the extensions specified in the look-ahead group.

Comment: still not working. can you please give structured example with <condition> tag?

Comment: You may try adding it like this: `<condition type="request-uri">^(?!.*\.(?:jpg|png|css|js)$).*$</condition>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a condition like this:

```
<condition type="request-uri">^(?!.*\.(?:jpg|png|css|js)$).*$</condition>
```

Accoring to the [specifiactions](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/manual/3.0/), you can check the `request-uri` type in the condition so as to check what it ends with:

> `request-uri` - Returns the part of this request's URL from the protocol name up to
>   the query string in the first line of the HTTP request

The negative look-ahead `(?!.*\.(?:jpg|png|css|js)$)` actually checks if the URI does not end with any of the extensions listed in the non-capturing group. You can add more extensions that you want to exclude after `|` symbol.

Comment: hi! one more problem arise today. I have url like http://www.example.com/Elink and I don't want Elink to be match with bootstrap, css, etc. So I have made a condition but it is not working, could you help ? the condition is <condition type="request-uri">^(?!.*(?:bootstrap|css|fonts|images|js|section|slidebars|author|authors|blog)$).*$</condition>

Comment: I see this regex will fail since you have to check if a string does not contain a word. This is the correct regex (with Elink): `^(?:(?!\b(?:Elink|bootstrap|css|fonts|images|js|section|slidebars|auth‌​or|authors|blog)\b).)*$`. I also added word boundaries, so `myblog` is accepted, just `blog` is not.

Comment: it's not working. since Elink is dynamic so it would change. Many other rules are also placed in my urlrewrite.xml, when I used your I found that the big url's like http://localhost:8080/ex/aaron/my-favorite/type/random There underline page is passed to the rule. I added that page to the list but still not working.

Comment: If something is "dynamic", what is the *pattern*? Regular expressions can only help if there is a known pattern, say, 4 English letters, followed by 5 digits, a whitespace, word boundary. My previous regex checks if there are no words "fonts", images", etc. in the whole URI, from the beginning to end. So the URL above will be passed to the rule.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I understand what you said. I rearranged rules, included both the rules for extensions as well as pages and now it is working fine. i.e.           <condition type="request-uri">^(?!.*\.(?:jpg|png|css|js|woff|ttf|svg)$)(?:(?!\b(?:bootstrap|css|fonts|images|js|section|slidebars|)\b).)*$</condition>

Comment: Great. Since `.*$` means *any number of characters but  a newline up to the end of string*, you can (and you have done it) further restrict this part of regex.